# Overlay a div directly on top of a sibling div

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design, woocommerce

I'm using Wordpress and have installed a plugin for WooCommerce that creates a zoom window for the product image. However, I can't get the zoom window to appear on top of the original product image. The code looks like this:

```
<div class="yith_magnifier_zoom_wrap">
<a class="yith_magnifier_zoom woocommerce-main-image" title="orange-slices" itemprop="image" href="orange-slices.jpg">
    <img class="attachment-shop_single wp-post-image" width="300" height="300" alt="orange-slices" src="orange-slices.jpg">
</a>
<div class="yith_magnifier_mousetrap" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; cursor: pointer;"></div>
<div class="yith_magnifier_zoom_magnifier" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 300px; height: 300px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image: url('orange-slices.jpg'); display: block; background-position: -7px -7px;"></div>
```

You can see the issue here: [WooCommerce product page](http://curious.notjustjargon.com/product/baby-treasure-basket-deluxe/)

I'm trying to center align the zoom window div `.yith_magnifier_zoom_magnifier` on top of the image div `.yith_magnifier_mousetrap`. I've managed to center it by making it `relative` and using `margin:0 auto;` but it now appears directly beneath the product image.

Unfortunately there's all sorts of inline rules applied by the theme and the plugin, so I need to override that, but I also need to keep the solution responsive as the product image height could vary. Any suggestions would be really welcome. Thankyou.

Comment: You need to reproduce the HTML and CSS here. I will point out that you're trying to wrap a couple of `<div>` elements inside an `<a>` element. Likely no good can come from that. Get your HTML straight, then look into relative versus absolute position in CSS.

Comment: Thank you. Added, although its quite a mess due to being derived from the theme and plugin. I think the `<a>` element is a sibling of the `<div>'s`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this way you don't need any magic number (e.g. a specific pixel size in the CSS):

```
.yith_magnifier_zoom_magnifier {
  position: absolute !important;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: This also seems to work. Again, massive thanks. I'll set this as the accepted answer because its lighter and less code. Thanks again kaosmos :)

Comment: You are welcome @SamCampsall, I'd like to insist that the main benefit of this code is that it doens't need to know the size of the image you are using.

Answer (score 1):

```
.yith_magnifier_mousetrap {
    top:-366px!important;
}
```

I think that is what you are trying to achieve?

**EDIT**

```
.yith_magnifier_zoom_magnifier {
    position: absolute !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    height: 100%!important;
    top: inherit!important;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%!important;
    margin-left: -150px!important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Craig, but unfortunately the image height could vary, so I need a responsive solution. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: The edit I have made horizontally centers the zoom element, whilst catering to any image height. As long as the image will always we 300px wide

Comment: Yes, it is always 300px, and yes, that works! I can only vaguely parse it, but you figured out in 5 mins what I've been staring at for two hours. Massive thanks Craig! :)